# Are my public Amazon S3 files listed anywhere?

Tags: wordpress, amazon-s3, woocommerce

I am seeting up a *Wordpress + WooCommerce* website that will be selling digital goods. For storing them we will be using *Amazon S3*.

The simplest and most viable option seems to be to upload files to S3, make them public and insert that link in WooCommerce product description. WooCommerce serves files through local links and amazon links do not seem to be visible anywhere except in admin panel.

**My question is**: when my files are public on Amazon are they listed anywhere? Meaning if I do not publish direct links anywhere is it safe to assume that there is no place to find it for other people?

Also how safe do you think such approach is? I understand that there are better options, like paid addons from WooThemes, but I would like to keep it more simple. What do you think guys?

Answer (score 0):

If you're making the files themselves public, Amazon won't be publishing a listing of them anywhere. If you're using them in posts, Google etc. will probably find and index them, but Amazon's not going to provide Google a list of them.

If you make the *bucket* public, Amazon shows users browsing the bucket itself a list of its contents.

Comment: So if I make the Bucket private it should solve the problem?
Is there any way to restrict usage of files to my site only? Something with specific URL for example?